# CSS Image not touching top

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation bar which is horizontal and touches both sizes of the screen. The only problem is that it doesn't touch the top (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nRQ7.png as you can see the yellow rectangle doesn't touch the top) I am already doing this in CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/test">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<ul>` got a default margin too, get rid of it in the CSS.

Comment: Check if the other elements you're using (i.e. div, ul, li) have a margin. Tools like your browser's developer tools or firebug can help you debug issues like this.

Comment: As an aside, there is a `<nav>` element that you probably want to use rather than `<div>`, unless you have a compelling reason not to.  The `<nav>` element is an extra clue to screen readers about the element's role on the page.

Comment: You could also use CSS reset or normalize to eliminate these kinds. Well it always isn't necessary to use them , but you need to know about them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<ul>` is set as display:block; by default.  You are seeing the line break that precedes it.  You have to account for that in your CSS with something like a margin-top:-10px;

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use:

```
 *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   /* I usually use this too: */
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This removes padding and margins from every element. Stops incidents like yours happening where I want everything to be flush. It gives me more control over the elements.

The issue, as other answers have stated, your `ul` has padding too. The above code will fix that and any future issues.